# Informal appointment reminder

Tags: informal-language

Tomorrow I have an appointment with another person to speak and train English. I want to remind him about this:

> We have an appointment on Wednesday at xx a.m, haven't we?

But it sounds too formal. It's only a private call.

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: In modern Present-day English, *We **have** (present simple) X, **don't** we?*, but *We **have done** (present perfect) X, **haven't** we?*. I think your version is slightly more formal than my versions solely by virtue of its being old-fashioned. I think some (older?) Brits might still talk that way, but most people don't talk like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good informal sentence would be:

> Are we still on for the English training on Wednesday at xx a.m.?